How many covariances can we draw between error estimates to modify the hypothesized model of CFA using AMOS?
I ran a confirmatory factor analysis in AMOS and the indices values required for model fit were below the required value so I draw covariance between error terms to modify model. the question I want to ask, is there any reference that guide about the number of covariances that we can draw to fit model? If there is then guide me. As I am learning AMOS first time so I do not have much knowledge of AMOS.
